# What is the cause of this StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I keep getting a `StackOverflowError` and I can't figure out why.
This is the exact error message

> java.lang.StackOverFlowError: null(in sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig)

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Component.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Sales_Center {

    JFrame mainf, loginf, newuserf;
    JButton submit, login, newuser;
    JPanel mainp, loginp, newuserp;
    JLabel userlbl, passlbl;
    JTextField usertxt, passtxt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rungui();
    }

    public Sales_Center() {

            loginf = new JFrame("Login");
            loginf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            loginf.setSize(new Dimension(275, 150));
            loginp = new JPanel();
            loginp.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 5));
            loginp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            loginp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 400));

            userlbl = new JLabel("Username: ");
            loginp.add(userlbl);

            usertxt = new JTextField(5);
            loginp.add(usertxt);

            passlbl = new JLabel("Password: ");
            loginp.add(passlbl);

            passtxt = new JTextField(5);
            loginp.add(passtxt);

            login = new JButton("Login");
            login.addActionListener(new loginb());
            loginp.add(login);

            newuser = new JButton("Creat Profile");
            newuser.addActionListener(new newuserb());
            loginp.add(newuser);

            //loginf.pack();
            loginf.setVisible(true);
            loginf.setContentPane(loginp);

    }

    public static void rungui() {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);

        Sales_Center gui = new Sales_Center();

    }
}

     class loginb extends Sales_Center implements ActionListener {

            String user, pass;

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                pass = passtxt.getText();
                user = usertxt.getText();
                Login login  = new Login(pass, user);


       } 
}
      class newuserb extends Sales_Center implements ActionListener {

          String user, pass;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        pass = passtxt.getText();
        user = usertxt.getText();
        NewProfile newprofile = new NewProfile(user, pass);

    }
}
```

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Each `Sales_Center` creates a `loginb` which is a `Sales_Center`, which will then create another `loginb`, which will create another, ....

Comment: Why do loginb and newuserb both extend Sales_Center? That makes no sense.  Note: you should follow conventions and name all classes beginning with a capital letter, and not using underscores.

Comment: Also, your naming convention is bananas. Please be consistent with naming.

Answer (score 3):

So man you have constructor of **Sales_Center** class where you perform following:

```
login.addActionListener(new loginb());
```

I see that **loginb** extends from **Sales_Center**. It means that constructor of **loginb** invokes constructor of super class. As you did not declare any constructor your result code will look like following:

```
class loginb extends Sales_Center {
    public loginb() {
        super();
    }
}
```

So what are happening? Answer is simple. Your parent class creates an instance of his child class and you have infinity recursion.
You try creating an instance of parent class which create his child class which creates his parent. It is happening again and again.